# Application access URL without displaying anything with Android

Tags: android

For example I have **token** variable in my android app.
I'm trying to send this variable to the server and run a query, so I'm using the following url with GET:
http://mywebsite.com/send.php?token=the_token

When user access this url, it adds the token to my database.

how I can make my android app automically access this URL on my `protected void onPostExecute(String token)` method?

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work (don't access the URL):

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    URL url;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://mywebsite.com/send.php?id="+token);
                        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

The toast works, and the URL is not accecced.

Another try:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                URL url;


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                url = new URL("http://example.com/send.php?id="+token);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what does the log say? `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: I don't get any error

Comment: why are you trying to make the api call in ui thread?

Comment: Try using HTTPUrlConnection instead of URLConnection http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: with HTTPUrlConnection you can check the response code.

Comment: I don't know, nothing appears, why is it so complicated just to open URL in background to save data...